# Normalizing data in R - dataframe construction

Tags: r, database-normalization, rpostgresql

I'm using R to connect to a database I have stored in PGAdmin so that I can add data into the database through R. Before adding the data into the database, it has to be normalized.

The dataset consists of employee data. If an employee is a manager, the `managing` column lists the employee ids of the employees that they manage.

I want to create a new dataframe in R that would represent my Managers table that has two columns: employee_id and manager_id (where manager_id is just the employee_id of the manager) that are both pulled from the original dataframe

How would I do this in R? Here's reproducible data:

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(first_name = c("Carrol", "Scott", "Michael", "Mary", 
"Jane", "Alex"), last_name = c("Dhin", "Peters", "Scott", "Smith", 
"Johnson", "Barter"), employee_id = c(412153L, 534253L, 643645L, 
765453L, 627234L, 174543L), email = c("carrol.dhin@company.com", 
"scott.peters@company.com", "michael.scott@company.com", "mary.smith@company.com", 
"jane.johnson@company.com", "alex.barter@company.com"), managing = c("174543", 
"", "", "", "534253, 643645", ""), department = c("Accounting", 
"Sales", "Sales", "Marketing", "Sales", "Accounting"), department_budget = c(500000L, 
1100000L, 1100000L, 750000L, 1100000L, 500000L), serial_number = c("KX6234", 
"FS5235", "LP5242", "GK6246", "KX6902", "BN7451"), manufacturer = c("Lenovo", 
"Lenovo", "Lenovo", "Lenovo", "Lenovo", "Lenovo"), model = c("X1 Gen 10", 
"T14s", "P1", "X1 Gen 10", "T15", "T14s"), date_assigned = c(44576L, 
44471L, 44341L, 44681L, 44606L, 44378L), installed_software = c("MS Office, Adobe Acrobat, Slack", 
"MS Office", "Mathcad, Adobe Acrobat", "", "MS Office, Slack", 
"Google Chrome")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))
```

Comment: Could you please add  reproducible data for the manager_id so we can understand how to connect with the data you `dput` already? Also, could please give an example of your desired output?

Comment: @SEAnalyst the manager_id is just the employee_id of the manager, the managing column lists all of the ids that that employee manages, all the data is contained in the test dataframe which is what I'm trying to breakdown and normalize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your sample data as `df`, you could use `select()` and `filter()` from `dplyr` to create a subset of managers.

```
library(dplyr)
managers <- df |> select("manager_id" =employee_id, 
                   "employee_id" =managing) %>%
  filter(.$employee_id!= "")
```

Result:

```
> managers
  manager_id    employee_id
1     412153         174543
2     627234 534253, 643645
```

Comment: is there a way to separate that second row into two rows? so that each employee_id has their own observation, it's okay if manager_id repeats

Comment: Yes, `tidyr` is a good option for this. With given output answer as `managers`, you can use `managers |> tidyr::separate_rows(employee_id)` to separate row number 2 into rows 2 and 3.